# IllegalArgumentException: defaultTarget must start with '/' or with 'http(s)'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to implement a persistent token based authentication with remember me functionality using spring security, where all configurations are annotation based. The problem is, when I am trying to run my application, server is throwing `IllegalArgumentException`. I'm also getting the message `Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception`. I have been stuck over a day and can't able to find any clue or suggestion. Please have a look on my code.

`SpringSecurityConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/","/list").access("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('DBA')")
            .antMatchers("/new-user", "/delete-user/*").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/edit-user/*").access("hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('USER')")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.jsp")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .usernameParameter("ssoid")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
            .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("logout")
            .and()
            .rememberMe()
                .rememberMeParameter("remeber-me")
                .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository)
                .tokenValiditySeconds(46800)
            .and().csrf()
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access_denied");
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception{
    builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    builder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider=new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return provider;
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
{
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices getPersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices() {
    PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices tokenBasedservice = new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(
            "remember-me", userDetailsService, persistentTokenRepository);
    return tokenBasedservice;
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationTrustResolver getAuthenticationTrustResolver() {
    return new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();
}
}
```

Configuration of spring filter chain

```
public class SecurityWebAppInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

I have a custom implementation of PersistentTokenRepository for Hibernate for creating, updating and removing the remember me token.

Complete stack trace of the error is,

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: defaultTarget must start with '/' or with 'http(s)'
    12:33:49.419 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl - HHH000031: Closing
    12:33:49.419 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl - Implicitly destroying Boot-strap registry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
    12:33:49.419 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl - Implicitly destroying ServiceRegistry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
    Jun 20, 2017 12:33:49 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
    SEVERE: Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: defaultTarget must start with '/' or with 'http(s)'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5097)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5615)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: defaultTarget must start with '/' or with 'http(s)'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        ... 25 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: defaultTarget must start with '/' or with 'http(s)'
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:68)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl(AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.java:138)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.LogoutConfigurer.getLogoutSuccessHandler(LogoutConfigurer.java:229)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.LogoutConfigurer.createLogoutFilter(LogoutConfigurer.java:295)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.LogoutConfigurer.configure(LogoutConfigurer.java:249)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.LogoutConfigurer.configure(LogoutConfigurer.java:62)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.configure(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:383)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:329)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:289)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:74)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:333)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$88510f6d.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$1(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$88510f6d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$77813f6b.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:355)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$88510f6d.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 26 more

    Jun 20, 2017 12:33:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: defaultTarget must start with '/' or with 'http(s)'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5097)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5615)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: defaultTarget must start with '/' or with 'http(s)'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        ... 25 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: defaultTarget must start with '/' or with 'http(s)'
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:68)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl(AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.java:138)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.LogoutConfigurer.getLogoutSuccessHandler(LogoutConfigurer.java:229)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.LogoutConfigurer.createLogoutFilter(LogoutConfigurer.java:295)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.LogoutConfigurer.configure(LogoutConfigurer.java:249)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.LogoutConfigurer.configure(LogoutConfigurer.java:62)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.configure(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:383)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:329)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:289)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:74)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:333)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$88510f6d.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$1(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$88510f6d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$77813f6b.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:355)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$88510f6d.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 26 more
```

I think the problem is in Security Configuration, but can't able to figure it out. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error says

```
.logoutSuccessUrl("logout")
```

must start with "http", "https" or "/"

Comment: i was getting he same error had my logoutSuccessUrl("logout") without "/", adding "/" worked for me i.e logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")

Comment: but how do you make that form use relative url?

Comment: by using `/`, the url is relative to the root of the servlet.  So if your servlet root is `https://my.domain/api`, then /logout would point to `https://my.domain/api/logout`

Comment: This solved my problem, but I am at a loss as how to map the error message to the .logoutSuccessUrl() call, there was nothing in my stack trace referencing that method.

Answer (score 0):

In the configure(HttpSecurity http) method in .logoutSuccessUrl("/signin") I added "/", everything worked.